# Different byte order in BPF program

Tags: c, endianness, ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I have two different types of BPF programs where I am printing the ip address with `bpf_printk("%pI4", &ipv4.s_addr);`. The xdp program is loaded in the loopback dev and the other is a bpf socket filter; i have a server and a client program that sends udp packets. The programs below print the ip address but each program prints (in /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe) the address in a different order. One is being printed as 127.0.0.1 (in the xdp program) and the other as 1.0.0.127. I understand that socket filters have access to a mirror of the kernel's skb_buff and xdp programs do not have access to this data as they are attached at an "earlier point". My question: Does the data in skb_buff data fields get "modified" to cpu endianness? What would be the cause of this different behavior?

Thank you in advance.

My env:

```
x86_64
clang-13
Little endian
Linux kernel 5.13
Ubuntu 21.10
```

```
// socket filter program
unsigned long long load_word(void *skb, unsigned long long off) asm("llvm.bpf.load.word");

SEC("socket/ipv4")
int filter_ipv4(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct in_addr ipv4;
    ipv4.s_addr = load_word(skb, BPF_NET_OFF + offsetof(struct iphdr, saddr));
    bpf_printk("%pI4", &ipv4.s_addr); // prints 1.0.0.127 
    return -1;
}

// xdp program

SEC("xdp_prog")
int xdp_some_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    struct ethhdr *ethh;
    struct hdr_cursor nh;
    int nh_type;
    struct in_addr ipv4;

    nh.pos = data;
    nh_type = parse_ethhdr(&nh, data_end, &ethh);

    if (nh_type == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP)) {
        struct iphdr *iph;

        nh_type = parse_iphdr(&nh, data_end, &iph);
        if (nh_type != IPPROTO_UDP)
            return XDP_PASS;

        ipv4.s_addr = iph->saddr;
        bpf_printk("%pI4", &ipv4.s_addr); // prints 127.0.0.1       
    }
    return XDP_PASS;
}

#define BPF_NET_OFF (-0x100000)
#define ETH_P_IP    0x0800  
#define IPPROTO_UDP    17

struct in_addr {
    __u32 s_addr;
};

struct ethhdr {
    unsigned char h_dest[6];
    unsigned char h_source[6];
    __be16 h_proto;
};

struct iphdr {
    __u8 ihl: 4;
    __u8 version: 4;
    __u8 tos;
    __be16 tot_len;
    __be16 id;
    __be16 frag_off;
    __u8 ttl;
    __u8 protocol;
    __sum16 check;
    __be32 saddr;
    __be32 daddr;
};


struct hdr_cursor {
    void *pos;
};

static __always_inline
int parse_ethhdr(struct hdr_cursor *nh, void *data_end, struct ethhdr **ethhdr)
{
    struct ethhdr *eth = nh->pos;

    if (eth + 1 > data_end)
        return -1;

    nh->pos = eth + 1;
    *ethhdr = eth;
    return eth->h_proto;
}

static __always_inline
int parse_iphdr(struct hdr_cursor *nh, void *data_end, struct iphdr **iphdr)
{
    struct iphdr *iph = nh->pos;
    int hdrsize;

    if (iph + 1 > data_end)
        return -1;

    hdrsize = iph->ihl * 4;

    /* ipv4 hdr is minimum 20 bytes */
    if (hdrsize  < sizeof(*iph))
        return -1;

    /* Variable-length IPv4 header, need to use byte-based arithmetic */
    if (nh->pos + hdrsize > data_end)
        return -1;

    nh->pos += hdrsize;
    *iphdr = iph;
    return iph->protocol;
}
```

Comment: Can't be bypass the issue by just accessing the addresses in `__sk_buff` since they are always network order? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.2/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L5337